# Do I need to retain mysqli_query() and mysqli_close()?

Tags: php, mysql

Do I still need to use mysqli_query($connection, $results); and mysqli_close($connection); ?

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO pawnshop ".
    "(Pawnshop_Name, Street, Barangay, City, DTI_Permit_No, Mayor_Permit_No, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Contact_Number, Email_Address, Password) ".
    "VALUES ".
    "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $sql->bind_param("ssssiissssss", $pawnshopName, $street, $barangay, $city, $dtiPermitNo, $mayorPermitNo, $firstName, $lastName, $middleName, $contactNumber, $email, $password);
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->get_results();   
    mysqli_query($connection, $results);// Do I still need this?
    mysqli_close($connection); //Do I still need this
```

Comment: Read the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - Short answer: no. Long answer. `mysqli_query($connection, $results);// Do I still need this?` **NO.** - `mysqli_close($connection); //Do I still need this` doesn't matter, just as long as you're not making another query below that, if you've more to do.

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection, $results);// Do I still need this?` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php `$result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))` if you're going to want to print rows, **yes.**

Comment: Can I use sql->close();? than mysqli_query() and mysqli_close().

Comment: I'm just going to store a data to the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this much part of the code is enough for you to finish querying database.

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO pawnshop ".
    "(Pawnshop_Name, Street, Barangay, City, DTI_Permit_No, Mayor_Permit_No, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Contact_Number, Email_Address, Password) ".
    "VALUES ".
    "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $sql->bind_param("ssssiissssss", $pawnshopName, $street, $barangay, $city, $dtiPermitNo, $mayorPermitNo, $firstName, $lastName, $middleName, $contactNumber, $email, $password);
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->get_results();
```

I see that you are mixing both OOP and Procedural Programming methods together by using `mysqli_close($connection)`, it is not a good practice even though you can do it. Instead use method in `$connection` object like `$connection->close()`;

Comment: mysqli_stmt_execute($sql); mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql); mysqli_stmt_close($sql); mysqli_close($connection); I have changed OOP to Procedural.. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no use of mysqli_query . u need to close prepared statement
by $stmt->close();

and also close the connection.

by $conn->close();